# Save an image from an axis handle - Matlab

Tags: matlab, handle

How can I save an image from the handle of an axis (handles.imageAxe) using imwrite or other native matlab function?

The  code:

```
% export_fig(handles.imageAxe, Name,  '-jpg -m2.5'); %// WORKS
imwrite(handles.imageAxe, Name); %// DOES NOT WORK
```

Comment: Error using imsave
Too many input arguments.

Comment: try imsave(handles.imageAxe)

Comment: Reference to non-existent field 'imageAxe'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The handle of the axis does not represent an 'image' in the matlab sense.

You can either:

A) export the figure:

```
saveas( handles.imageAxe , 'mysavedfig.jpg' )
```

or

B) capture a frame (*the content of the axis*) with `getframe`, then write an actual `image`

```
F = getframe(handles.imageAxe) ;
imwrite(F.cdata,'mysavedframe.jpg','jpg')
```

Read the doc for [`saveas`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/saveas.html), [`getframe`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/getframe.html) and [`imwrite`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html) to better tune it to your needs.